# How to display Hoefler Text ornament glyphs

Tags: symbols, unicode, hoefler

I'm trying to use Hoefler Text F043 and F044 to separate sections in a document, but not managing it in XeLaTex, with MacTex 2014. I tried:

```
\char"61507
```

but that doesn't work.
I tried:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{f043}{\myglyph}
\myglyph
```

and that doesn't work either. Actually, `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` is an `undefined control sequence` - I might have to search how to use that... In any case, what is the best to insert these ornaments in my document?

Comment: Did you try `\char"F043` and `\char"F044`, respectively?

Comment: Yes - I did: \char"F043 just gives me a blank square in the PDF output... which is sort of an improvement on not even compiling :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works using either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX from MacTeX2014:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}
\newfontfamily{\HTOrn}{HoeflerText-Ornaments}
\begin{document}
{\HTOrn \char"F043 \char"F044}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could create a macro named, say, `\SeparateTwoSections` to simplify the insertion of this visual separator between paragraphs, sections, etc:

```
\newcommand\SeparateTwoSections{\begin{center}\HTOrn\char"F043\char"F044\end{center}}
```

Comment: Yes! I am a newbie, and not at all comfortable with fonts - so I had set the main font to Hoefler Text, which does not contain the ornaments (?)

Comment: The positions `F043` and `F044` in "Hoefler Text" are indeed empty.

Comment: @Frank - I've edited the example code to make it more obvious how one might use both "Hoefler Text" and "Hoefler Text Ornaments", side by side.

Comment: - Well - except the \HTorn bit - if I include that in a \newcommand, it says that \newcommand is an undefined control sequence when I try to use it... - never mind, I had a typo on the "O" of "Orn". Thanks again!